# Reactjs datetime value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am using React js and I have difficulties getting value/data from my datetime picker.

Here's my input field:

```
<Form className="form1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <label>Date Started: </label>
  <Datetime dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
            timeformat='hh-mm-ss'
            value={this.state.datestartedV}
            onChange={this.props.handleDatestarted} />

  <label>Date Ended: </label>
  <Datetime dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD'
            timeformat='hh-mm-ss'
            value={this.state.dateendedV}
            onChange={this.props.handleDateended} />

  <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>SubmitRequest</Button>
</Form>
```

Here's my listener:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Date is: ' + this.state.datestartedV + this.state.dateendedV); 
}

handleDatestarted(event) {
  this.setState({datestartedV: event.target.value});
}

handleDateended(event) {
  this.setState({dateendedV: event.target.value}); 
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {datestartedV: ''};
  this.state = {dateendedV: ''};
  this.handleDatestarted = this.handleDatestarted.bind(this);
  this.handleDateended = this.handleDateended.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of event.target.value in handleDatestarted?

Comment: what do you mean sir? should I assign/replace the 'value' in the event.target.value  with the real date? sorry i'm still an ignorant student :(

Comment: I thought that's the line how to get the value/data from my datetime field..

Comment: Please do a console.log(event.target.value) in your handDatestarted function and then let us know what that says when it is called.

Comment: I am done doing that before sir but it has no outputs. and I think this problem has something to do with the initialization of my 'this.state'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialy, `this.state.datestartedV` is undefined because you overwrite the initial state with a second state definition.

Change your constructor to:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
       datestartedV: '',
       dateendedV: ''
  };
  this.handleDatestarted = this.handleDatestarted.bind(this);
  this.handleDateended = this.handleDateended.bind(this);
}
```

Assuming your question's code is all in *one* component then you have to use your functions without `.props` this way:

```
     onChange={this.handleDatestarted}
```

and

```
     onChange={this.handleDateended}
```

Comment: thank's mate, honestly it gives me no output when I follow you're advised but you give me a hint to solved my problem.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take the `target.value`. Because it returns a `moment()` ([more info](http://momentjs.com/))which represent a JavaScript Date object.

You can simply try this. *(event itself is a `Date` Object. You can rename it to `startDate` to make more sense)*

```
handleDatestarted(event){
    this.setState({datestartedV: event});
}
```

Comment: it still no outputs sir.